# FileZilla (or OSX app) to SFTP after SSH authentication

Tags: macos, ssh, ftp

Basically, I have to SSH to what I assume is the firewall of my job, then from there i SSH to another server to do my work. 
My problem is I want to be able to move files back and forth, like FileZilla allows when one uses a regular FTP.

Any Advice?

PS: OSX please

```
#---------------------------Respond to Response -----------
```

thank you! great link. I actually did not know it was called multi-hop and that alone got me where i wanted. But, even though the raw way of doing it, as u show in your answer is great, but was trying to make the link method work. I setup the keygen-paswordless entry and works great, but below is confusing. Maybe cause his figure is showing 3 connections? But where does the username go in this? i tried adding user@server instead of example without the user@ part below but that did not work :(
below is my failures note that i am using his terminology but i changed server name etc (and double checked them)

```
Host ruapehu
HostName ruapehu.example.com

Host aoraki
ProxyCommand ssh -q ruapehu nc -q0 aoraki 22

Host tongariro
ProxyCommand ssh -q aoraki nc -q0 %h 22

#------------ second try

Host username   
HostName ruapehu.example.com
Host aoraki   
ProxyCommand ssh -q ruapehu nc -q0 aoraki 22
Host tongariro   
ProxyCommand ssh -q aoraki nc -q0 %h 22


#------------ third try

Host ruapehu   
HostName username@ruapehu.example.com
Host aoraki   
ProxyCommand ssh -q ruapehu nc -q0 aoraki 22
Host tongariro   
ProxyCommand ssh -q aoraki nc -q0 %h 22
```

Comment: You should be able to do this via port forwarding, assuming you don't have firewalls blocking the ports.

Comment: thx for reply! I am not sure what you mean. I am not talking about my own network. I am trying to get on to my work's network (login allows me access to attached network computers,... ) then I have to ssh to a one of those computers. so I have no access to any firewall ports or port forwarding. I just know I SSH one time. then SSH another time. Then I can use terminal in that place I want. but I can't do that with FileZilla (or alike) to transfer files to my server so later I can run code on them.

Comment: You don't need access to anything except the SSH connection.  IF you can SSH, you can generally [port forward](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) (assuming the ports aren't blocked in the firewall).  You can chain forwarded ports together.

Comment: If I read this right, you are at home, SSH to server1, and then you need to SSH to server2 where you actually do your work in server2. And you want to copy files from server 2 to your home (and vice versa) is this right?

Comment: Yes oh Great Persian King Darius :p and I cant directly go from home to server 2 because its not on the internet unless you go through server 1

Comment: The mac version of netcat does not have the -q option. You must remove it.

Comment: i accepted your answer, but above still does not work, i remove -q but again I am not sure above allows for username...

Comment: I know this is old but to help others... Just add `User __USERNAME__` to the config under each host to add a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go from home to server 2 in one leap, if you have set up passwordless login on server 1, by doing

```
  ssh  -t user@server1  ssh  -t user@server2
```

At this point you can use scp as if you were directly linked to to server2. If this solution suits you, you can automate slightly better by means of the ProxyConnect option, you can find a good guide on http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html.

Comment: My comment is too long so I am posting to original question. thx